# Standard re-installation of Windows 11 - not selectable "keep personal files and apps" - What's the Reg Edit fix?

Tags: windows-11, windows-installation, clean-install

What's the Reg Edit navigation to change these options?

Bit embarrassed I need to ask, I'm a computer enthusiast and just have a 15 year habit of installing clean windows on separate partition and re-install anytime I want for that new computer feeling. That's fine for my 4 family-use PC's.

My laptop however runs Windows 11 and I have a extensive software that I dont want to re-install, and so occasionally i re-install Windows and choose "keep personal files and apps" although this time that option is not selectable.

I have done this twice with this laptop with Windows 11. I have tried running from 'setup' and booting directly from a bootable drive.

Can someone help with the reg edit navigation so I can fix, or advise me what else I may need to do?

Cheers,

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the installation file that you got is for the same Windows version/variant as currently installed?

Comment: "What's the Reg Edit navigation to change these options?" - They don't exist; Honestly it sounds like you are trying to install a Windows 11 build that is lower then the build you already have installed.  Since you have provided almost no information.  That is only a educated guess, in that I have seen this behavior, only when that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

> "keep personal files and apps" although this time that option is not
> selectable.

It means that the Windows installation has changed enough from what is there the Windows cannot create Windows.old properly.

I have had this happen once or twice.

Version changes, original system damaged, things like that. Windows 10 /11 needs to be in good enough condition for "Keep Everything" to work.

You cannot do anything except back up first and then install as it is requiring.

Most of the time, just not all of the time Windows Reset will keep everything.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Yeah I meant to make an image but didn't - so I'll make an image when I have it rebuilt and setup the way I like.

Comment: Install and keep everything does not work all of the time - it does work most of the time. So my answer above applies here.